# Drupal7 with IE9 new session

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, drupal-7, session-cookies

In `IE9`, there is a function called `new session`. I have login to drupal in one IE window. Then I tried `new session` in IE9. However, the new session window has logined to the account (which is supposed not to be logined by the `new session` feature).

[Session Cookies, sessionStorage, and IE8 or “How can I log into two webmail accounts at the same time?”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx)

I have tried to use `new session` on facebook and it works. I'm wordering why it doesn't work on IE9 and find some solution to fix it.